# Understanding the concept of lifting the state up in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I have a bug in my code. Specifically, the setPostList([...postList, post]) does not seem to work correctly.

I am not able to successfully lift the state up. Why is my code not working?

I don't think the postList array is being updated. I tried it using the spread setPostList([...postList,post]) but that did not work, I also tried pushing using a call back function into the array but that did not work either.

Here is my Modal

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  AlertDialog,
  AlertDialogAction,
  AlertDialogCancel,
  AlertDialogContent,
  AlertDialogDescription,
  AlertDialogFooter,
  AlertDialogHeader,
  AlertDialogTitle,
  AlertDialogTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/alert-dialog";
 
const Modal = (props) => {
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState("");
  const [body, setBody] = useState("");
 
  return (
    <>
      <AlertDialog>
        <AlertDialogTrigger
          style={{
            border: "1px solid black",
            padding: "10px 40px",
            borderRadius: "4px",
          }}
        >
          Create An Announcement
        </AlertDialogTrigger>
        <AlertDialogContent>
          <AlertDialogHeader>
            <AlertDialogTitle>Publish A New Announcement:</AlertDialogTitle>
 
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Your Name"
              onChange={props.changeMessageAuthor}
            />
            <textarea
              type="text"
              rows={5}
              placeholder="Type your announcement here ..."
              onChange={props.changeMessageBody}
            />
 
            <AlertDialogDescription>
              <span className="text-emerald-600 text-xl font-black">
                Review Your Announcement:
              </span>
              <br />
              <span className="font-black">
                Author:
                <br />
                {author}
                {props.author}
              </span>
              <br />
              <span className="font-black">Announcement:</span>
              <br /> {props.body}
            </AlertDialogDescription>
          </AlertDialogHeader>
          <AlertDialogFooter>
            <AlertDialogCancel>Cancel</AlertDialogCancel>
            <AlertDialogAction onClick={props.addAnnouncement}>
              Publish
            </AlertDialogAction>
          </AlertDialogFooter>
        </AlertDialogContent>
      </AlertDialog>
    </>
  );
};
 
export default Modal;
```

Here is my PostList

```js
//Here is my PostList

import postcss from "postcss";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Modal from "./Modal";
 
const PostList = () => {
  const [body, setBody] = useState("");
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState("");
  const [postList, setPostList] = useState([]);
  const [post, setPost] = useState({});
 
  const handleMessageBody = (event) => {
    setBody(event.target.value);
  };
 
  const handleMessageAuthor = (event) => {
    setAuthor(event.target.value);
  };
 
  const handleAddingAnnouncement = (event, author, body) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setPost({ author: author, body: body });
    setPostList([...postList, post]);
    console.log(postList[0]);
  };
 
  return (
    <>
      <hr />
      <br />
      <Modal
        author={author}
        body={body}
        changeMessageAuthor={handleMessageAuthor}
        changeMessageBody={handleMessageBody}
        addAnnouncement={handleAddingAnnouncement}
      />
      <br />
      {postList.length > 0 && postList.map((e) => e.body)}
      {postList.length === 0 && <h1>loading...</h1>}
    </>
  );
};
 
export default PostList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're encountering a common issue in React regarding the asynchronous nature of state updates. The problem lies in how you're handling the state update in `handleAddingAnnouncement`.

When you call `setPostList([...postList, post])`, you're attempting to update `postList` with the current value of `post`. However, since `setPostList` is asynchronous, the state update may not have happened by the time you access `postList` again in the next line. As a result, you're not getting the updated value of `postList`.

To fix this, you can use the functional update form of `setPostList`, which takes a function as an argument. This function receives the current state as its argument, allowing you to safely update state based on the previous state:

```js
const handleAddingAnnouncement = (event, author, body) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const newPost = { author: author, body: body };
  setPostList(prevPostList => [...prevPostList, newPost]);
};
```

By using the functional form, you ensure that you're always working with the latest state. This should resolve the issue you're encountering with the state not updating correctly.

Comment: Thank you I will also give this a try to see if also works

Answer (score 0):

I made a change to how I am handling submitting and now it works - also I know preventDefault() was in the submit to begin with

```js
  // const handleAddingAnnouncement = (event, author, body) => {
  //   event.preventDefault();
  //   setPostList((prev) => {
  //     const myList = [...prev];
  //     myList.push({
  //       id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
  //       author: author,
  //       body: body,
  //     });
  //     console.log
  //     return myList;
  //   });
  // };

  const handleAddingAnnouncement = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setPostList([
      ...postList,
      { id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000), author: author, body: body },
    ]);
  };
```